# How to order by an associated model in Rails 4, and specify a direction?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails 3.2.17, i could have the following:

```
scope :sorted, -> { joins(:other).order({:other => :code}, :code) }
```

Which produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT [things].* FROM [things] INNER JOIN [others] ON [others].[id] = [things].[other_id] ORDER BY [others].[code] ASC, [things].[code] ASC
```

The same code in Rails 4.0.4 gives the following error, however:

```
Direction should be :asc or :desc
```

But, I cannot figure out a way to keep the ordering and specify the direct. The scope below, for example, gives the same error:

```
scope :sorted, -> { joins(:other).order({:other => {:code => :asc}}, :code => :asc) }
```

EDIT: To be clear, I want to use the Hash style syntax and do not want to write raw SQL strings

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12730

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug in Rails 4.0+ (something about `order` accepting nested hashes)

I found a [Github issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12730) for you explaining the issue

They recommend using `source:`, but that's only for an association declaration. If you find the answer, I will gladly remove this, but hopefully it will help you!

Comment: Thanks Rich, following your link I found this [PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/12743). I have added a comment, but at the moment it looks as though this behaviour is just not supported. Very annoying!